# Cannot read property 'title' of null error when using Vue with Django Rest Framework When LimitOffsetPagination

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

As a test to use Vue to do a GET on a Django Rest Framework api url, it appears to work fine and I will get a listing of the tutorial title and rendering of the tutorial id in my links as expected:

My html file:

```
<li v-for="tutorial in tutorials">
    <a href="/tutorial/[[ tutorial.id ]]/">
        [[ tutorial.title | title ]]
    </a>
    at [[ tutorial.created ]] by [[ tutorial.author ]]
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        data: {
            tutorials: {}
        },
        mounted() {
          axios.get('/api/tutorials/').then(response => {
            this.tutorials = response.data
          })
        }
    });
</script>
```

As far as the rest api goes for Django, the serializer used in Django is:

```
class TutorialSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
author = serializers.StringRelatedField()
class Meta:
    model = Tutorial
    fields = [
        "title",
        "description",
        "summary",
        "author",
        "graphic",
        "created",
        "modified",
        "is_approved",
        "is_published",
        "publish_date",
    ]
```

But when I introduce a limit like so in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': \
        'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
}
```

I now get this in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
at eval (eval at Ya (vue:6), <anonymous>:3:331)
at wn.vt [as _l] (vue:6)
at wn.eval (eval at Ya (vue:6), <anonymous>:3:177)
at wn.e._render (vue:6)
at wn.r (vue:6)
at fn.get (vue:6)
at fn.run (vue:6)
at un (vue:6)
at Array.<anonymous> (vue:6)
at qe (vue:6)
```

By the way, using the Django admin to view the Rest API works fine. Anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

And it never fails that when I take the time to ask a good question, the answer appears within a minute or two of what needs to be done.

I needed to use:

```
axios.get('/api/tutorials/').then(response => {
        this.tutorials = response.data.results
      })
```

How did I know? Because I used curl (like I should have originally) and found the actual returned values when I added this pagination filter. :-\ Anyways, I want to keep this here in case anyone screwed up like I did and didn't research properly. I've been doing this for years and I still make mistakes like this. :-)